# How to deal with "Problem went away but I don't know why"?

Tags: discussion, answers, unanswered-questions

I observed one [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26817810/didregisterforremotenotificationswithdevicetoken-never-called-on-specific-device) on SO. Nothing wrong with the question, everything seems fine - the OP gave thorough explanation of his problem, people reacted in comments, one answer appeared - nothing out of the ordinary. **BUT** the resolution of the question, described in the comments is:

> interestingly, the problem went away, and I don't know why

My question is - how should be these situations handled? Surely the OP could answer his own question - "problem solved" and accept it, but that doesn't answer the question and it doesn't help other users seeking help. Any other answers by other users could be wild guesses because the OP has no way of verifying the answer (~ *too localized*) as the problem is now gone. Closing the question is out of the question as well, judging by the upvotes, so is the question doomed to be in the *unanswered* section forever?

Comment: Ah, the joy of [heisenbugs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug)!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Presumably the existing information in the question is insufficient to allow anyone else to reproduce/answer it since the OP can't any more.

So, the following off-topic close reason would seem to apply

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

(emphasis mine)

Given that you've raised it here, the meta effect may well see it closed for this reason.

Comment: I guess you're right, but then again - maybe those *+6* mean that there are some people having this problem. But one can only guess and simply close it.

Comment: If they are having their own problem one of them needs to ask their own question with steps that actually can reproduce the issue. They can always link to the closed question if it has any useful information.